# New Relic Provisioning Failed on Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, newrelic

I'm trying to add New Relic through the Azure Store to one of my subscriptions.  After clicking through the dialogs, it starts creating the add-on and then fails.  In the details of the error message is this:

> Account subscriptions is invalid. Subscription product can't be blank.

I've also gone to the New Relic site and created a free account but that didn't change anything.  My Azure subscription is one I've had for years.

Any ideas/advice are appreciated.

Comment: I receive an error on the confirmation page, saying NewRelic *can't provide a billing estimate at this time.* I suspect it's an issue on NewRelic's side, especially since I'm seeing a different error than you.

Comment: Could be.  I opened a support ticket with them.  Will update here as soon as I get it resolved.